# How to generate session_id by sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, session

My tracking system do not generate sessions IDS.
I have user_id & event_date_time.
I need a new session_id for each user's session that starts 30 minutes or more after last event_date_time of each user.

My final goal is to calculate median session time.

I tried to generate session_id=1 and session_id=2 once event_date_time-next_event_time>30 and guid=guid, but i'm stuck from here

```
  select a.*,
  case when (a.next_event_date-a.event_date)*24*60<30 and userID=next_userID 
  then 1
  when (a.next_event_date-a.event_date)*24*60>=30 and userID=next_userID then 
  2
  end session_id        
  from
  (select f.userID,
  lead(f.userID) over (partition by f.guid order by f.event_date) 
  next_guid,                          
  f.event_date,   
  lead(f.event_date) over (partition by f.guid order by f.event_date) 
  next_event_date                                    
  from event_table f 
  )a
  where next_event_date is not null
```

Comment: Do you have control over the application code? Or are you trying to do this entirely in the database? A bit more detail on what you're trying to accomplish here would help

Comment: No i'm trying to do it localy in some dashboard that i'm developing. In order to calculate the median session time.

Comment: And what do the guids represent here?

Comment: It represents user id, i updated it in the query

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track using `lead` or `lag`. My recommendation would be to break this into steps and create a temp table to work against:

1. With the first query, assign every record its own unique ID, either a sequence number or GUID. You could also capture some of the lagged data in this step.
2. With a second query, find the overlaps (< 30 minutes) and make the overlapping records all the same -- either the same as the earliest or latest in that grouping, doesn't matter as long as it's consistent.

Something like this:

```
create table events_temp as (
select f.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by f.userID order by f.event_date) as user_row,
       lag(f.userID) over (partition by f.userID order by f.event_date) as prev_userID,
       lag(f.event_date) over (partition by f.userID order by f.event_date) as prev_event_date
from event_table f 
order by f.userId, f.event_date
)

select a.*,
       case when prev_userID = userID
                   and 24 * 60 * (event_date - prev_event_date) < 30
                 then lag(user_row) over (partition by userID order by user_row)
            else user_row
           end as session_id
from events_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you could generate ID's this way:

```
select  id, guid, event_date, 
        sum(chg) over (partition by guid order by event_date) session_id
  from (
    select id, guid, event_date,   
           case when lag(guid) over (partition by guid order by event_date) = guid 
                 and 24 * 60 * (event_date -lag(event_date) 
                                over (partition by guid order by event_date) ) < 30
                then 0 else 1
           end chg
      from event_table ) a
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48ac51ba42e7f41d0cbddec09f86f6cd)</sup>**

Compare neighbouring rows, if there are different guids or time difference is greater than 30 minutes then assign 1. Then sum these values analytically.